# error while use '' pip install torch-geometric '' ,ERROR: Failed building wheel for llvmlite

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip, llvmlite

error while use '' pip install torch-geometric '' ,ERROR: Failed building wheel for llvmlite
Dependence:
windows
VS studio 2017 
python 3.5.2

```
tensorboard              1.8.0
absl-py                  0.9.0
astor                    0.8.1
bleach                   1.5.0
cachetools               4.0.0

certifi                  2019.11.28
chardet                  3.0.4
cluster                  1.4.1.post2
cycler                   0.10.0
decorator                4.4.2
enum34                   1.1.9
future                   0.18.2
gast                     0.2.2
google-auth              1.11.2
google-auth-oauthlib     0.4.1
google-pasta             0.1.8
grpcio                   1.27.2
h5py                     2.10.0
html5lib                 0.9999999
idna                     2.9
imageio                  2.8.0
joblib                   0.14.1
jsonpatch                1.25
jsonpointer              2.0
Keras-Applications       1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing      1.1.0
kiwisolver               1.1.0
Markdown                 3.2.1
matplotlib               3.0.3
networkx                 2.4
numpy                    1.17.4
oauthlib                 3.1.0
opt-einsum               3.1.0
pandas                   0.24.2
Pillow                   7.1.1
pip                      20.1.1
protobuf                 3.11.3
pyasn1                   0.4.8
pyasn1-modules           0.2.8
pyparsing                2.4.6
python-dateutil          2.8.1
pytz                     2019.3
PyWavelets               1.1.1
pyzmq                    19.0.0
requests                 2.23.0
requests-oauthlib        1.3.0
rsa                      4.0
scikit-image             0.15.0
scikit-learn             0.22
scipy                    1.4.1
seaborn                  0.9.1
setuptools               45.2.0
six                      1.14.0
tensorboard              1.8.0
tensorboard-plugin-wit   1.6.0.post3
tensorboardX             2.0
tensorflow               1.8.0
tensorflow-estimator     2.1.0
tensorflow-gpu-estimator 2.1.0
tensorflow-tensorboard   0.4.0
termcolor                1.1.0
torch                    1.5.0
torchfile                0.1.0
torchnet                 0.0.4
torchvision              0.6.0
tornado                  6.0.4
tqdm                     4.45.0
urllib3                  1.25.8
visdom                   0.1.8.9
websocket-client         0.57.0
Werkzeug                 1.0.0
wheel                    0.34.2
wrapt                    1.12.0
```

when I use 'pip install torch-geometric' in cmd,error occur as followed
emmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
Error information：

```
Building wheels for collected packages: llvmlite
  Building wheel for llvmlite (setup.py) ... \  WARNING: Subprocess output does not appear to be encoded as cp936
error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\64846\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\64846\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-q8bqrutu\\llvmlite\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\64846\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-q8bqrutu\\llvmlite\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\64846\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-oxukaky2'
       cwd: C:\Users\64846\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-q8bqrutu\llvmlite\
  Complete output (77 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  c:\users\64846\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\python.exe C:\Users\64846\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-q8bqrutu\llvmlite\ffi\build.py
  -- Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.17134.
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
    Failed to run MSBuild command:

      MSBuild.exe

    to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

      绯荤粺鎵句笉鍒版寚瀹氱殑鏂囦欢銆\x82



  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/64846/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpn2vuc6_6/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.15.26729.0
  -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.15.26729.0
  -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.15.26726/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe
  -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.15.26726/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe - works
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
  -- Detecting C compile features
  -- Detecting C compile features - done
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.15.26726/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.15.26726/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe - works
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
  -- Detecting CXX compile features
  -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
  -- Configuring done
  -- Generating done
  -- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/64846/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpfbd6c988
  -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.15.26729.0
  -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.15.26729.0
  -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.15.26726/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe
  -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.15.26726/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe - works
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
  -- Detecting C compile features
  -- Detecting C compile features - done
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.15.26726/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.15.26726/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe - works
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
  -- Detecting CXX compile features
  -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package):
    Could not find a package configuration file provided by "LLVM" with any of
    the following names:

      LLVMConfig.cmake
      llvm-config.cmake

    Add the installation prefix of "LLVM" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
    "LLVM_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "LLVM"
    provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
    installed.


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/64846/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-q8bqrutu/llvmlite/ffi/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  Trying generator 'Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64'
  Trying generator 'Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64'
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\64846\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-q8bqrutu\llvmlite\ffi\build.py", line 192, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\64846\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-q8bqrutu\llvmlite\ffi\build.py", line 180, in main
      main_win32()
    File "C:\Users\64846\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-q8bqrutu\llvmlite\ffi\build.py", line 94, in main_win32
      try_cmake(here_dir, build_dir, generator)
    File "C:\Users\64846\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-q8bqrutu\llvmlite\ffi\build.py", line 28, in try_cmake
      subprocess.check_call(['cmake', '-G', generator, cmake_dir])
    File "c:\users\64846\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 581, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '-G', 'Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64', 'C:\\Users\\64846\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-q8bqrutu\\llvmlite\\ffi']' returned non-zero exit status 1
  error: command 'c:\\users\\64846\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\python.exe' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for llvmlite
```

I'm very new to this field,thanks for your help

Comment: What is the file not found, i.e. "系统找不到指定的文件"? What is this in english?

Comment: @FlyingTeller,maybe is Trying generator 'Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64'

Comment: It does look like it is trying to call `cmake` but failing. Do you have a working cmake setup?

Comment: @FlyingTeller，I am a freshman,emmm,my computer has visual studio 2017 and my OS is windows，maybe I have working cmake setup

Comment: From what you describe you don't. try downloading and installing it from [here](http://www.cmake.org/). Is there any specific reason why you are using python 3.5 by the way?

Comment: @ FlyingTeller,maybe I don't desribe my problems clearly,emm,I have already update my error information and have installed CMAKE,could you help me ?

Comment: Please make sure to use appropriate formatting for your error message. Wrap it in three ` to have it formatted as code - much more readable

Comment: @ FlyingTeller,thx,I try to wrap it with three `,But stackoverflow say that my post mostly are code,It doesn't allow me to save the edit.Now,I have update error message .Could you help me

Comment: @ FlyingTeller，could you help me ,I have no idea

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this web interface](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/installation.html) to select your torch-geometric version correctly.
For example If I put PyTorch1.10.* + Linux + pip + CPU I can use this command:

```
pip install torch-scatter torch-sparse torch-cluster torch-spline-conv torch-geometric -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.10.0+cpu.html
```

If you have installed a Pythorch version < 1.9.* maybe you will have problems. I suggest creating an empty venv and install inside with the command that [this web interface](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/installation.html) create.
(Also I suggest to use at least python >=3.6, but maybe is not necessary)